# Django: Creating categories using querysets/filtering

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, django-mptt

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create categories using custom filters.

I am building an e-commerce app and I have set up my category model using mptt. I am importing a csv that creates my top level categories which works fine. The problem is I will need to have sub-categories that are more specific e.g Men's Clothing(Top Level) > Jeans.

The csv has several fields that contains info relating to each product e.g description: "stone wash bootcut jeans". I would ideally like to check these fields for keywords and add each product to the correct categories. Is it possible to set up categories this way or is there an alternative solution?

I am a django newbie so any help is appreciated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug',))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_slug_list(self):
        try:
            ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        except:
            ancestors = []
        else:
            ancestors = [ i.slug for i in ancestors]
        slugs = []
        for i in range(len(ancestors)):
            slugs.append('/'.join(ancestors[:i+1]))
        return slugs


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Brands(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name


class Product(models.Model):
    aw_deep_link = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    aw_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    search_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    merchant_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    display_price = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    brand_name = TreeForeignKey('Brands', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    rrp_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

**importCSV.py**

```
import re
from products.models import Category, Brands
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Load some sample data into the db"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--file', dest='file', help='File to load')

    def handle(self, **options):
        from products.models import Product

        if options['file']:
            print("Importing " + options['file'])

            with open(options['file']) as f:
                linecount = 0
                next(f)
                for line in f:
                    linecount += 1
                    fields = line.split(',')
                    category = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=fields[10])
                    brand_name = Brands.objects.get_or_create(brand_name=fields[7])

                    data = {
                            'aw_deep_link':  fields[0],
                            'description': fields[1],
                            'product_name': fields[2],
                            'aw_image_url':  fields[3],
                            'search_price':  fields[4],
                            'merchant_name': fields[5],
                            'display_price':  fields[6],
                            'brand_name':  brand_name[0],
                            'colour' :  fields[8],
                            'rrp_price' :  fields[9],
                            'category' :  category[0],

                    }

                    product = Product(**data)
                    product.save()

                print("Added {0} products".format(linecount))
```

Comment: So you don't know your subcategories in advance but want an intelligent algorithm that reads the text and understands its meaning well enough to be able to decide which of the words would make up a good subcategory? That sounds like "Natural Language Processing", a task for machine learning. It would probably be easier to take the time and define your categories manually. Of course you could do a simple word count across all your text fields. This may help _you_ to identify what's relevant.

Comment: I would have pre-defined categories and sub-categories. The top level would be created by the csv and all sub-categories would be created manually. I'm trying to figure out how I can import the csv and have each product assigned to the correct sub-category @ascripter

Comment: Can you assume exactly one sub-category keyword will always be present? Or can it be zero? Can it be more than one?

Comment: There would be a minimum of one keyword and there may be variations of the word e.g trainers/runners. So if a keyword was mentioned in any of the data fields, it would assign the product to the correct category e.g Men’s Footwear > Trainers. @ascripter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

- Manually predefined subcategories that may comprise more than one keyword
- Several text fields for each Product where it is assured that any of the keywords appears at least once

From this setup I would at first try to generalize the "search term" for each subcategroy, maybe by a regex, depending on the complexity of conditions that you need to identify a subcategory. Most probably a list of synonyms is already sufficient. Add such a field to your `Category` model (here a regex solution):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    regex = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)  # only needed for subcategories (top level from csv)
    ...
```

For your example where `trainers` and `runners` would be equivalent (to my English knowledge these are plural words here, so **not** equivalent to `trainer` or `runner` appearing anywhere), this would by (as a regex) `r'trainers|runners'`

This is the part you need define manually - I don't envy your for the tedious work involved ;)

Afterwards, your import loop would need some changes around here:

```
def handle(self, **options):
    from products.models import Product, Category
    all_categories = list(Category.objects.all())
    # converted to list to evaluate Queryset and don't query again in the loop below
```

and here

```
                data = ...
                for textfield in ('description', 'product_name'):
                    # I suppose these are the two relevant fields to scan?
                    subcat = None
                    for cat in all_categories:
                        if re.search(cat.regex, data[textfield]) is not None:
                            if cat.is_leaf_node():
                                # only consider nodes that have no children
                                subcat = cat
                                break
                    if subcat is not None:
                        break
                # subcat is now the first matching subcategory
                if subcat is not None:
                    data['category'] = subcat


                product = Product(**data)
```

Complete

```
import re
from products.models import Category, Brands
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Load some sample data into the db"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--file', dest='file', help='File to load')

    def handle(self, **options):
        from products.models import Product, Category
        all_categories = list(Category.objects.all())

        if options['file']:
            print("Importing " + options['file'])

            with open(options['file']) as f:
                linecount = 0
                next(f)
                for line in f:
                    linecount += 1
                    fields = line.split(',')
                    category = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=fields[10])
                    brand_name = Brands.objects.get_or_create(brand_name=fields[7])

                    data = {
                            'aw_deep_link':  fields[0],
                            'description': fields[1],
                            'product_name': fields[2],
                            'aw_image_url':  fields[3],
                            'search_price':  fields[4],
                            'merchant_name': fields[5],
                            'display_price':  fields[6],
                            'brand_name':  brand_name[0],
                            'colour' :  fields[8],
                            'rrp_price' :  fields[9],
                            'category' :  category[0],

                    }

                    for textfield in ('description', 'product_name'):
                        # I suppose these are the two relevant fields to scan?
                        subcat = None
                        for cat in all_categories:
                            if re.search(cat.regex, data[textfield]) is not None:
                                if cat.is_leaf_node():
                                    # only consider nodes that have no children
                                    subcat = cat
                                    break
                        if subcat is not None:
                            break
                    # subcat is now the first matching subcategory
                    if subcat is not None:
                        data['category'] = subcat

                    product = Product(**data)
                    product.save()

                print("Added {0} products".format(linecount))
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm just slightly confused on how or where I create the regex. I understand it may be something like this - Trainers = r'trainers|runners' for each subcategory but I'm unsure how I implement it @ascripter

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood your previous comment stating _I would have pre-defined categories and sub-categories_. You could add them via the django admin for example. Or write them in a csv and import from there.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm explaining this badly. I do have pre-defined categories and sub-categories (which have been created manually via admin). I'm just unsure how regex in models work. With the example of trainers being the sub-category and trainers/runners being the keywords, how and where would I write that? @ascripter

Comment: For the admin, it is just a simple textfield (or `CharField`). You have to add that field to your model. A regex pattern is just a string. Maybe have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). This string is then used in the line with `re.search(cat.regex, ...)` as a regex pattern. If the pattern matches somewhere in the text you analyse, `re.search` will return a MatchObject, otherwise `None`. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thanks for your help and patience. I understand  what I have to do, now for the tedious work.

Comment: If it's really a helpful answer, please approve it and vote it up :)

Comment: I've tried to vote for your answer several times however it will not allow it as I'm new and have a reputation less than 15. Once I have the ability to vote for it I will :)

Comment: Is it be possible to import products to every category that matches a regex expression rather than just one, so several categories would be updated with the same product during the import. I'm having trouble with parent categories not inheriting their children's objects and I think this may be a better option. @ascripter

Comment: You mean a product won't be associated with a parent category, but only the child category you assigned it to? That sounds somehow like an issue with `mptt` and probably the implementation of `TreeForeignKey`. If you can track the problem down to that, post another question about it - however I'm not familiar with `mptt`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If "trainers" matched the regex, subcategory Trainers is updated with the product and the parent category "Men's Footwear" is left empty. I believe it is a mptt issue, but I think I will have issues with regex as well. If Trainers has a subcategory Hi-tops, the regex will match the parent category before it gets a chance to evaluate the subcategory @ascripter

Comment: Just edited my answer to only consider only leaf nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, it results in all products being set to the first category instance for some reason, and nothing appears in subcategories @ascripter

Comment: With _first category_ you mean the root node, top level? That's really weird. As if there were no leaf nodes at all. Try debugging it, maybe counting the times the line `subcat = cat` is reached at all. If it's not reached, then it's got something to do with mptt.

Comment: I've tried debugging it. The script is assigning every product to the leaf node of the first category(top level/root node) that appears in the CSV.  @ascripter

Comment: That sounds like the regex search never returns `None`. I've checked again taht part. [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is supposed to return `None` if the pattern doesn't match. Can you post a list of some of the matched categories and their regex?

Comment: - Childrens Footwear, 
- Mens Accessories, 
- Mens Clothing, 
- Mens Footwear
- - - Trainers (regex is 'trainers')

Comment: And which of them is the leaf node where everything is assigned to? What's its regex?

Comment: I'm just testing with this at the moment and it will assign everything to 'Childrens Footwear'. Your original code worked fine in this case but if I add another subcategory to trainers I'll have issues.

Comment: If I added a subcategory or subcategories to 'Childrens Footwear', it would assign everything to the leaf node of 'Childrens Footwear'.

Comment: And does this newly created subcategory have a non-blank regex? A blank would match **every** string

Comment: I've tested it using a blank regex and a non-blank regex and the results are the same

Comment: If you've got a valid regex everywhere, and you still get products assigned to a category where the regex definitely **doesn't** match, it must be an issue with mptt. Maybe your tree is corrupt? I've seen there is a [`rebuild`](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html?highlight=rebuild#rebuild) method

Comment: I've actually realised that top-level categories have a blank regex and that is matching every string. Sorry I should have seen that sooner.

Comment: Does it work with non-blank root categories? Actually that shouldn't matter since only leaf nodes are considered by the code. If that resolved the issue anyways, I highly suspect some problems with your tree structure since it would imply that `is_leaf_node()` returns `True` on root nodes.

Comment: I had some categories without subcategories while testing and they had a blank regex, so they were the leaf node of that category. The solution works for leaf nodes and root nodes however if there are 3 levels of categories (e.g Mens Footwear >>> Trainers >>> Hi-Tops), the middle category will not be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, that's what you wanted, isn't it? Otherwise you have to replace `if cat.is_leaf_node():` by _cat is not root node_ or whatever criterion you need.

Comment: It would need to start at the leaf node and work its way up, so if Hi-Tops regex was not matched, then Trainers regex would be checked next.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a well defined sub-task. Try to do it yourself. If you get stuck, ask another question about ordering mptt TreeQuerySets from leaf to root, so that the leaves are checked first. This will keep things cleaner here :)

Comment: I'll try my best. Thanks again for all the help. Hopefully I can solve the rest by myself :)